# getMethods() returns method I haven't defined when implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, reflection, interface

An simple interface:

```
interface Foo {
    void myMethod(String arg);
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
    void myMethod(String arg){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class cls = FooImpl.class;
    try {
        for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
        System.out.print(method.getName() + "\t");
        for(Class paramCls : method.getParameterTypes()){
            System.out.print(paramCls.getName() + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
myMethod java.lang.String,
...//Other Method
```

Only one myMethod is printed.

But if I change the interface to a generic one:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    void myMethod(T arg);    
}   

class FooImpl implements Foo<String> {
    void myMethod(String arg){}
}
```

Then strangely the output will be:

```
myMethod java.lang.Object,
myMethod java.lang.String,
...//Other Method
```

Why after changing the interface to a generic one will lead to one more Method with a parameter type Object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first method is a [bridge method](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.be/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html), created by the compiler.
If you test your methods for '[isBridge()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isBridge%28%29)', you can filter out the 'wrong' methods (also filters out some strange results you can get with covariance returns).

Following code will not print the `myMethod java.lang.Object`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class FooImpl implements Foo<String> {
    public void myMethod(String arg) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class cls = FooImpl.class;
        for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
            if (!method.isBridge()) {
                System.out.print(method.getName() + "\t");

                for (Class paramCls : method.getParameterTypes()) {

                    System.out.print(paramCls.getName() + ",");

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

interface Foo<T> {
    public void myMethod(T arg);
}
```

Comment: Looking into "what is a bridge method" now.

Comment: Read this tutorial, it explains all: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
        for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
    //these methods are called bridge methods       
            if(!method.isBridge()){
                System.out.print(method.getName() + "\t");
                for(Class paramCls : method.getParameterTypes()){
                    System.out.print(paramCls.getName() + ",");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

**UPDATE:** [Bridge methods](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.in/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html)

Quoting the blog:

> Bridge methods in Java are synthetic methods, which are necessary to
>   implement some of Java language features. The best known samples are
>   covariant return type and a case in generics when erasure of base
>   method's arguments differs from the actual method being invoked.

**UPDATE CODE** FROM above blog:

```
public class SampleTwo {
    public static class A<T> {
        public T getT(T args) {
            return args;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A<String> {
        public String getT(String args) {
            return args;
        }
    }
}
```

On compiling the code will look like:

```
public SampleThree$B();
...
public java.lang.String getT(java.lang.String);
Code:
0:   aload_1
1:   areturn

public java.lang.Object getT(java.lang.Object);
Code:
0:   aload_0
1:   aload_1
2:   checkcast       #2; //class java/lang/String
5:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method getT:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
8:   areturn
}
```

> the bridge method, which overrides method from base class "A", not
>   just calling one with string argument (#3), but also performs type
>   cast to "java.lang.String" (#2). It means, that if you will execute
>   following code, ignoring compiler's "unchecked" warning, the result
>   will be ClassCastException thrown from the bridge method:

```
A a = new B();
a.getT(new Object()));
```